# Merge different rows of an array using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have a JSON array which has the following entries:

```
[{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr1":"ABC","attr2":"001"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr3":"XYZ","attr4":"123"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr1":"DEF","attr2":"002"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr3":"DDD","attr4":"222"}]
```

Is there a way, using lodash, I can merge the array so that this becomes:

```
[{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr1":"ABC","attr2":"001","attr3":"XYZ","attr4":"123"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr1":"DEF","attr2":"002","attr3":"DDD","attr4":"222"}]
```

Basically use the "date" attribute to merge multiple rows with different JSON attributes into a single JSON object entry ?

Comment: What should happen if the `date` values are the same but the `customer` values are different (is that not possible with your data)?

Comment: The customer would be the same always.

Comment: What version of lodash are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#groupBy) to group the objects by date. Then [`_.merge()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#merge) each group:

```js
var customers = [{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr1":"ABC","attr2":"001"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr3":"XYZ","attr4":"123"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr1":"DEF","attr2":"002"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr3":"DDD","attr4":"222"}];

var result = _(customers)
  .groupBy('date') // group the objects by date
  .map(function(item) { // map each group
    return _.merge.apply(_, item); // merge all objects in the group
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using lodash 3.10.1. I assumed you want to merge each pair and that the second element of a pair will override existing properties from the first one (if there are such).

```
var source  = [{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr1":"ABC","attr2":"001"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"10.10.2014","attr3":"XYZ","attr4":"123"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr1":"DEF","attr2":"002"},{"customer":"xyz","date":"11.10.2014","attr3":"DDD","attr4":"222"}];

var chunked = _.chunk(source, 2);

var result = _.map(chunked, _.spread(_.merge));

console.log(result);
```

And here is a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/redoci/edit?js,console).